# how to randomize JSON in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How can i randomize my following JSON in angularjs???

```
{
  "1": {
            "id": "1",
            "que": "Grand Central Terminal, Park Avenue, New York is the world's",
            "options": {
                "A": "largest railway station",
                "B": "highest railway station",
                "C": "longest railway station",
                "D": "None of the above"
            },
            "ans": "A"
        },
 "2": {
            "id": "2",
            "que": "Entomology is the science that studies",
            "options": {
                "A": "Behavior of human beings",
                "B": "Insects",
                "C": "The origin and history of technical and scientific terms",
                "D": "The formation of rocks"
            },
            "ans": "B"
        },
 "3": {
            "id": "3",
            "que": "Eritrea, which became the 182nd member of the UN in 1993, is in the continent of",
            "options": {
                "A": "Asia",
                "B": "Africa",
                "C": "Europe",
                "D": "Australia"
            },
            "ans": "B"
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by randomizing a JSON ?

Comment: I am working on quiz application for that i need to randomize my questions ... How can i randomize those questions ?? I have already converted my JSON using $map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your task easier i would suggest you use an array of objects like this one:

```
var questions=
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "que": "Grand Central Terminal, Park Avenue, New York is the world's",
        "options": {
            "A": "largest railway station",
            "B": "highest railway station",
            "C": "longest railway station",
            "D": "None of the above"
        },
        "ans": "A"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "que": "Entomology is the science that studies",
        "options": {
            "A": "Behavior of human beings",
            "B": "Insects",
            "C": "The origin and history of technical and scientific terms",
            "D": "The formation of rocks"
        },
        "ans": "B"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "que": "Eritrea, which became the 182nd member of the UN in 1993, is in the continent of",
        "options": {
            "A": "Asia",
            "B": "Africa",
            "C": "Europe",
            "D": "Australia"
        },
        "ans": "B"
    }
]
```

And then to select a random question use:

```
$scope.randomQuestion = questions[Math.floor(Math.random()*questions.length)];
```

Comment: thankyou all .. I will try and update you if any issues are there

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to convert your questions Object to an Array, so you can randomize the questions order:

http://plnkr.co/edit/PSeh0BLNjK5ydXJrLguw?p=preview

```
<p ng-repeat="q in questionsArray | orderBy: random">{{q.key}} - {{q.val.que}}</p>
```